# How can append user input to the end of an array and display all elements?

Tags: php, html, forms

At the top of the page, I have a text box and a submit button. The user is prompted to enter their name.  Below this, I want to start to list the names entered.  If you enter a name, it should appear below on the list.  If you then enter another name and hit submit, both names should appear, and so on.

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action = ""  method = "post">
        List Name: <input type="text" name="listname"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
        </form>


        <br/><br/>
        <form action = ""  method = "post">
        Add a new item: <input type="text" name="new_item"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>

    <?php
    $current_items[]=$_POST["new_item"];
    foreach ($current_items as $x)
    echo $x . "<br/>";

    echo "Current items on list";
    $current_items = array();

    ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Post your code in your question.

Comment: Perhaps you should use a database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'hard' part here is storing your list of names across multiple requests. There are a couple of options, depending on the use case.

If you need to store the names for multiple users, you'll have to store them in some sort of database or file storage. If you want to show them just to the current user you either store them in session, or post them back and forward on each request. I went for the last options, as it is probably th easiest way. have a look at the code below.

```
<form  method="post">
Add a new item: <input type="text" name="new_name"/>
<input type="submit"/>

<?php
$names = postVar('names') ? : array();
$names[] = postVar('new_name');
foreach ($names as $name) {
    echo $name . "<br/>";
    echo "<input type='hidden' name='names[]' value='$name'/>";
}
echo "Current items on list";

function postVar($name) {
    // only if exists
    if (! isset($_POST[$name])) {
        return null;
    }
    // fetch
    $out = $_POST[$name];
    // cleanup
    if (is_array($out)) {
        return array_map('htmlspecialchars', $out);
    }
    return htmlspecialchars($out);
}
?>

</form>
```

The big difference is that I added each name in your list as a hidden variable to the page. This way you can read them on each request and rebuild your list. By adding the `[]` to the name it gets returned as an array, which is very handy here. And off course I had to move your closing form tag down to make sure they get posted with the form.

Note that I added a small cleanup function. Your code is fine for a demo, but should NEVER be used in production. It is wide open to Javascript injection, and will produce warnings if your post variable does not exist. You should never use unsantized user input on a page. I also renamed your variables, just so the code would be a bit better readable.

Let me know if you want me to explain the code any further.